# How to change a particular section of code at a mass scale?

Tags: python, java, parsing, code-generation

I want to scan a code base with approximately 150k python + java files and want to find a specific kind of hardcoding. For ex:

```
# some code above
if get_city() == 'Delhi': # they way of checking can be different like city = get_city() and then checking city == 'Delhi'
   country = 'India'
else: 
    country = 'US'
# some code below
```

Now I want to move this hardcoding to a configuration like

```
---
'delhi': 'India'
'SanFransico': 'US'
'paris': 'France'
```

and change the code to

```
# some code above
data = yaml.loads(city_mapping)
country = data[get_city()]
# some code below
```

How to find such code patterns and change them programmatically?

Comment: Is it always exactly the same `if/else` ?

Comment: Are you restricted to specific parser generators `yacc` and `lex` as in the tags, or is this a generic syntax analysis question?

Comment: Hardcodings can be a switch case also, the only thing that is fixed is either use of `get_city()` function or we can check the codebase with city literals like 'Delhi', etc

Comment: @DmitriChubarov this is generic syntax where conditional sentences can have hardcodings and we want to move those hardcodings to configuration

Comment: I would then suggest `code-generation` and `parsing` tags for this question

Comment: I want suggestion regarding the same how can I do that?

Comment: How can we get the list of variables which are changing in the `if` clause because I want them to export to config file